# What's the equivalent to $SAFE=4?

Tags: ruby, eval

I was playing with threads and eval when ran into an issue. My code is:

```
thread = Thread.start {
  $SAFE = 4;
  eval("`touch ~/test`")
}
thread.join
```

But it results in an error:

```
ArgumentError: $SAFE=4 is obsolete
    from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
```

I found that `$SAFE=4` became obsolete in [Ruby 2.1](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/NEWS.html#label-Built-in+global+variables+compatibility+issues):

> $SAFE=4 is obsolete. If $SAFE is set to 4 or larger, an ArgumentError is raised.

But it is not mentioned what should be used instead. Is there an equivalent to `$SAFE=4`? Basically what I want is to run `eval` the safest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I could see is to exploit Binding for safe evals

http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/2.1.0/Binding

```
class Demo
  def initialize(n)
    @secret = n
  end
  def get_binding
    return binding()
  end
end

k1 = Demo.new(99)
b1 = k1.get_binding
k2 = Demo.new(-3)
b2 = k2.get_binding

eval("@secret", b1)   #=> 99
eval("@secret", b2)   #=> -3
eval("@secret")       #=> nil
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent everything. For example, `eval("ENV['FOO'] = 'bar'", b1)` will still affect the outside.